# d3.js create stacked bar chart from values in object

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The below code will create a bar chart of a single value within the array of objects called ‘data’. How can I use the collection of data to create a stacked bar chart?

set up the margins

```
 var w = 700;
 var    h = 500;
 var margin = {
    top: 58,
 bottom: 120,
    left: 60,
    right: 40
};
var width = w - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

define the data

```
 data =[
 { name: "Subway", carbs: "480", fat: "400", protein: "120", sum: "1000"}, 
 { name: "Steak & Potatos", carbs: "900", fat: "350", protein: "200", sum:    "1450"}, 
 { name: "Sausage", carbs: "50", fat: "350", protein: "80", sum: "480"} 
 ];
```

I want the height of the bar to be the sum of the values for carbs, fat,     protein, but with each value to be of a different color.
define x

```
 var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(data.map(function(e){
        return e.name;
    }))
    .rangeBands([0,width]);
```

define y. This is where I think I need help

```
 var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d,i){

        return parseInt(d.carbs) ;
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

The above will give me a bar with a single value (carbs). But what I really want to do is to create a stacked bar chart. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Added after below posted answer 'z is your color scale here which will decide what your rectangles look like'

```
 var z = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#ff0", "#f00", "#0ff"])
.domain(["carbs", "fat", "protein"]);
```

This is the plot function which draws the chart

```
 function plot(params){

    this.append('g')
    .call(params.gridlines)
    .classed('gridline', true)
    .attr('transform','translate(0,0)');

    this.selectAll('bar')
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .classed('bar', true)
    .attr('x', function(d,i){
        return x(d.name)
    })
    .attr('y',function(d,i){
        return y(d.carbs);
    })
    .attr('width', function(d){
        return x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr('height', function(d,i){
        return height - y(d.carbs)
    })
    .style('fill',function(d,i){
        return ordinal_color_scale(i);
    });

this.selectAll('.bar_label')
        .data(params.data)
        .enter()
            .append('text')
            .classed('bar_label', true)
            .attr('x', function(d,i){
                return x(d.name) + (x.rangeBand()/2);
            })
            .attr('dx', 0)
            .attr('y', function(d,i){
                    return y(d.carbs);
                })
            .attr('dy', -6)
            .text(function(d){
                return d.carbs;
            });

        this.append('g')
            .classed('x axis', true)
            .style('fill', '#ffd000')
            .attr('transform','translate('+ 0 +','+ height +')')
            .call(params.axis.x)
                .selectAll('text')
                .style('text-anchor','end')
                .attr( 'dx', -8)
                .attr('dy',8)
                .attr('transform','translate(0,0) rotate(-45)');

        this.append('g')
            .classed('y axis', true)
            .style('fill', '#ffd000')
            .attr('transform','translate(0,0)')
            .call(params.axis.y);
}

plot.call(chart, {
    data: data,
    axis: {
        x: x_axis,
        y: y_axis
    },
    gridlines: y_gridlines
});
```

What I don't understand is how to draw the z variable in the bars on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain for y is indeed what's wrong here. The range needs take all the variables into account, not just carbs. In other words, your `max` function needs to consider the sum of all properties.

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d,i){
        return parseInt(d.sum);
})])
.range([height, 0]);
```

This is because, in the end, your bars will be as high as the sum of all your properties (since it's a stacked bar graph)

You will then need to use the [`stack`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#stacks) function when you actually draw your `<rect>` elements. Each bar will contain 3 `<rect>` elements (one for carbs, fat and protein stacked one on top of the other) You didn't post any code for that but it will most likely look like :

```
// z is your color scale here which will decide what your rectangles look like
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#<colorForCarbs>", "#<colorForFat>", "#<colorForProtein>"])
    .domain(["carbs", "fat", "protein"]);

g.selectAll(".serie")
.data(stack.keys(["carbs", "fat", "protein"])(data))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d) { return d; })
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr(class, 'bar')
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.name); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

A "serie" in the example is, for example, all the rectangles that are related to "carbs" (as opposed to a stack that would contain the 3 rectangles for carbs, fat and protein).

This example should give you everything you need if you are missing something : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

**EDIT**

With your updated question, this is the section of the code where you should be using the z scale

```
this.selectAll('bar')
    .data(params.data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .classed('bar', true)
    .attr('x', function(d,i){
        return x(d.name)
    })
    .attr('y',function(d,i){
        return y(d.carbs);
    })
    .attr('width', function(d){
        return x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr('height', function(d,i){
        return height - y(d.carbs)
    })
    .style('fill',function(d,i){
        return ordinal_color_scale(i);
    });
```

Instead of that, use

```
var stack = d3.stack(); 
g.selectAll(".serie")
    .data(stack.keys(["carbs", "fat", "protein"])(data))
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "serie")
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
       .data(function(d) { return d; })
       .enter()
       .append("rect")
           .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.name); })
           .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
           .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
           .attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

Comment: I added the z variable changed it to scale.ordinal because scaleOrdinal was getting this error 'Uncaught TypeError: d3.scaleOrdinal is not a function(…)'. 
I want to note that I copied the code in the linked example you gave me, and the code worked with its d3 library, but not with the one in my library. That is wierd!

Comment: OK, that's because you use d3 v3 (and my code used d3 v4). Shouldn't really change much. See my edit

Comment: When I use d3 v4 and switch scale.ordinal to scaleOrdinal, then I get the error saying: 'd3.scaleOrdinal(...).domain(...).rangeBands is not a function(…)'.  Am I getting any closer?

Comment: Yes, very close I think ! Use `x.bandwidth()` instead of `x.rangeBand()`

Comment: OK, now I get this error: stack.keys is not a function(…).

Comment: Did you add the `var stack = d3.stack();` before the statetement ?

Comment: If I do I get this error: 'd3.stack is not a function(…)'. But if I use d3.layout.stack I get the other error. 'stack.keys is not a function(…)'. Both give me no bars.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. The function definitely exists in d3 v4. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zorwer?editors=1111

Comment: I'll check out your codepen links and keep trying and if I get it I'll post here if I figure it out. Thanks!.