# d3 v4 nested data and stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked-chart

I am trying to make a chart that looks like this: [image: Example Bar Chart]

I have a D3.nest data structure that looks like this:

```
{"key":"Area 1","values":[
    {"key":"5. Validation Complete","value":12.5},
    {"key":"Deferred","value":1},
    {"key":"3. Identify & Validate Proposed Solutions","value":5},
    {"key":"1. Define & Describe the Problem or Opportunity","value":0}]},
{"key":"Area 2","values":[
    {"key":"5. Validation Complete","value":41.2},
    {"key":"4. Implement the Solutions","value":86.6},
    {"key":"3. Identify & Validate Proposed Solutions","value":6},
    {"key":"2. Identify Root Causes","value":4},
    {"key":"1. Define & Describe the Problem or Opportunity","value":9}]},
{"key":"Area 3","values":[
    {"key":"5. Validation Complete","value":40},
    {"key":"4. Implement the Solutions","value":49.2},
    {"key":"3. Identify & Validate Proposed Solutions","value":10.4}]},
{"key":"Area 4","values":[
    {"key":"Deferred","value":0.25},
    {"key":"4. Implement the Solutions","value":28},
    {"key":"3. Identify & Validate Proposed Solutions","value":84.9},
    {"key":"2. Identify Root Causes","value":0}]}
```

My zKeys is structured as:

[image: Array Image]

I have unsuccessfully tried [Bostock's Stacked Bar Chart Example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) and this SO  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518438/d3-js-create-stacked-bar-chart-from-values-in-object).

Here is my code:

```
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#F8A11E", "#E51F36", "#582C85", "#1C92D0", "#017165", "#7F7F7F"]);    

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var sharepointStatusArray = getListData("Points List","ID,Title,Color_Code");
var data=getListData("Points%20List","$select=Area,StatusID,Points,Status/Title&$expand=Status");   

var zKeys = [];

sharepointStatusArray.forEach(function(d)
 {
    zKeys.push(d.Title);
 });

var nestData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Area; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Status.Title; })
    .rollup(function(v) { return d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Points; }); })
    .entries(data);

    nestData.sort(function(a,b) {return b.total - a.total;});
    x.domain(nestData.map(function(d) { return d.key; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(nestData, function(d){return d3.sum(d.values, function(d){return d.value})})+20]).nice();
    z.domain(zKeys) 

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll(".serie")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(zKeys)(nestData))
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class","serie")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
        .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key);})
            .attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.data.key);})         
            .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1]);})
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("Hours");


    //Creating legend for colors
      var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(zKeys.slice())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

I cannot get the stacked bar chart to draw according to the examples. Almost every example out there for this uses d3.csv and not d3.nest so I am at a loss as to how those examples translate to a d3.nest scenario with an output array.

Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Reading and debugging carefully this example can help too https://gist.github.com/caravinden/8979a6c1063a4022cbd738b4498a0ba6. The data will most likely fits the scheme

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to my own question. 
One of the things I discovered was that all the information I found that dealt with d3.stack() stated that the data that was sent to the function needed to be 2D (2 dimensional). This was something that d3.nest() outputs nicely. This turned out to not be accurate. 
I should have done this from the beginning, but I debugged the example [Mike Bostock’s Stacked Bar Chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) and discovered that the output of d3.csv() that everyone uses in their examples actually outputs a 1D array with each element containing key/value pairs of the data to be displayed in each rect.
[image: Screenshot of the data output from Mike's example]

I've probably made a very roundabout way of doing it, but here is what I did to solve my problem of not having the right data structure for d3.stack().

1) I kept my usage of d3.nest() output because it allowed me to sum up individual values into single key/value pairs for each element like this:

[image: Nested Data]

2) I then sanitized that data output using the following code to get it to look like the output of the d3.csv() in all the examples (adding key/value defaults for missing data and flattening the structure:

```
//BEGIN data cleanup for d3.stack
//Add default values for missing data points to make each array formatted the same
    nestData = nestData.map(function(keyObj) {
        return {
            key: keyObj.key,
            values: zKeys.map(function(k) { 
                    value = keyObj.values.filter(function(v) { return v.key == k; })[0];
                    return value || ({key: k, value: 0});
                })
        };
    });

//Loop through the nested array and create a new array element that converts each individual nested element into a key/value pair in a single object.
var flatData = [];
nestData.forEach(function(d) {
    var obj = { Area: d.key }
        d.values.forEach(function(f) {
            obj[f.key] = f.value;
        });
    flatData.push(obj);
  });
//END data cleanup for d3.stack
```

The data now looked like this:
[image: Flattened Structure]

3) After the data sanitizing I was then able to use the code from Mike's example out of the box like so:

```
    x.domain(flatData.map(function(d) { return d.Area; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(nestData, function(d){return d3.sum(d.values, function(d){return d.value})})+20]);
    z.domain(zKeys) 

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.stack().keys(zKeys)(flatData))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.data.Area); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```