# D3 - Stacked Bar Chart - Only use certain columns CSV - Counting distinct elements

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am trying to figure out how to use D3 and I am having two issues. One problem is essentially using the data in certain columns of my CSV file. Also, the In this case, the only information I really need in the CSV is the Residence column, School Year column, and the Major column. I am struggling to use the provided csv and essentially get my program to read just those columns and ignore the name column, and the ID column. The second issue is being able to count the number of distinct majors in each column and that being my height of the bar and the bar chart is divided by certain groups. For example, if I were to look at one residence hall, I see that in the residence hall, there is a distinct count of 8 majors in the residence hall. So 8 would be the height of the bar and the subgroups would be the school year. In this case, there are 3 Sophomores, 2 freshman, 1 senior, and 2 seniors. So the single bar would be divided into 4 categories accordingly. I am assuming to count the number of distinct majors, I would use d3.nest() and then after use d3.stack() to do the stacked bar graph.

```
d3.csv("/data/students.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

CSV:
Essentially you are at university where you have various students of different school years, with various majors living in certain buildings .

```
Name, Residence, ID, School Year, Major
Bill Thornton, Davis Hall, 11123, Sophomore, Mathematics
Savannah Lipscombe, Jameson Hall, 11231, Freshman, Biology
Jay Price, Davis Hall, 12222, Senior, Business
...
Hassan Abdullah, Arthur Hall, 11111, Junior, Mechanical Engineering
Jo Park, Reed Hall, 22123, Freshman, Political Science
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [d3 v4 nested data and stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319869/d3-v4-nested-data-and-stacked-bar-chart)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44319869/d3-v4-nested-data-and-stacked-bar-chart), `d3.nest` and `d3.stack` don't work too well together. Instead, you can process your data with vanilla JavaScript into the following format:

```
[ { Residence: string, [year]: number; } ]
```

So for example

```
[ { Residence: "Davis Hall", "Sophomore": 1, "Freshman": 2 } ]
```

Then the stacked bar chart follows from there.

You also have some spaces in your data, are those really there or did you put them there for readability? I removed them in any case.

```js
const dataString = `Name, Residence, ID, School Year, Major
Bill Thornton, Davis Hall, 11123, Sophomore, Mathematics
Savannah Lipscombe, Jameson Hall, 11231, Freshman, Biology
Jay Price, Davis Hall, 12222, Senior, Business
Hassan Abdullah, Arthur Hall, 11111, Junior, Mechanical Engineering
Jo Park, Reed Hall, 22123, Freshman, Political Science`.replace(/, /g, ",");

const unique = array => array.filter((v, i) => array.indexOf(v) === i);

const data = d3.csvParse(dataString);
const years = unique(data.map(d => d["School Year"]));
const residences = unique(data.map(d => d.Residence));

const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 35,
    left: 35,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const countedData = residences.map(r => {
  const result = {
    Residence: r
  };
  years.forEach(year => {
    result[year] = [];
  });

  data.filter(d => d.Residence === r)
    .forEach(d => {
      result[d["School Year"]].push(d.Major);
    });

  years.forEach(year => {
    result[year] = unique(result[year]).length;
  });
  return result;
});

console.log(countedData);

const x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
  .domain(residences)
  .padding(0.1)

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(countedData, d => d3.sum(years.map(y => d[y])))])
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["steelblue", "darkorange", "lightblue"])
  .domain(years);

const xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .attr("class", "x-axis")

const yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .attr("class", "y-axis")

svg.selectAll(".y-axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(null, "s"))

svg.selectAll(".x-axis")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
    .tickSizeOuter(0))

const stackedData = d3.stack().keys(years)(countedData);
console.log(stackedData);

const group = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
  .data(stackedData, d => d.key)

group.exit().remove()

group.enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("layer", true)
  .attr("fill", d => z(d.key));

const bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(d => d, e => e.data.Residence);

bars.exit().remove()

bars.enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .merge(bars)
  .attr("x", d => x(d.data.Residence))
  .attr("y", d => y(d[1]))
  .attr("height", d => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="700" height="300"></svg>
```